# Run query based on result of previous query in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hoping someone can help me with this. I've been using PHP for a while, but am new to Codeigniter.

Basically I have two tables on two seperate databases called 'photos' and 'users'. 'photos' contains info regarding the photo the user wants to view, and then 'users' contains info on the user who owns that photo.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Viewphoto_model extends CI_Model {


    public function get_photo($id)
    {
        $db_photos = $this->load->database('photos', TRUE);
        $db_photos->select('*');
        $db_photos->select("DATE_FORMAT(uploaddate, '%d/%m/%y') as uploaddate_formatted", FALSE);
        $db_photos->from('photos');
        $db_photos->where('approved', '1');
        $db_photos->where('id', $id);

        $query = $db_photos->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

So basically it grabs the row on the database based on the ID the user enteres into the URL.

It works fine.

In each row on the 'photos' table is a user ID number which is the ID number of a row on the 'users' database/table. I want to be able to get the relevent row from the 'users' table based on the ID number in the row on the 'photos' table.

I've been trying to find the answer but have had no luck as of yet. Do I want to do a join across 2 databases or maybe pass a value from the get_photo function to a 2nd function that runs a 2nd query? How can it be done?

The way I would have thought to do it is get the userid value from the result of the first query and then put it into a 2nd query in a 2nd function? How do I do that?

Any help is most appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work in theory, not had much practice with codeigniter AR.

```
$db_photos->select(
      "u.*, DATE_FORMAT(p.uploaddate, '%d/%m/%y') as uploaddate_formatted"
      , FALSE);
$db_photos->from('photos as p');
$this->db->join('users as u', 'u.id = p.user_id', 'left');
```

include your where clauses...

NOTE { Should you not be finding users, then their photo's ? }

try this

```
//Should work Provided!! Configs are in this Order
//$db['photos']['']
//$db['default']['']


//First Query ( Users ) 
$q1 = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id'=>$id));


//Second Query (photos)
$db_photos = $this->load->database('photos', TRUE);
$q2 = $db_photos->select("DATE_FORMAT(uploaddate, '%d/%m/%y') as uploaddate_formatted", FALSE)
                  ->from('photos')
                  ->where('approved', (int)1);
                  ->where('userid', $q1->row()->id)
                  ->get();

var_dump($q1);
var_dump($q2);

//you job now is to build and object/array of the combined queries
//I dont know enough about the outcome to make those judgments
```

Comment: The tables are on seperate databases though, how can I do a join on two tables located on two databases?

Comment: Not sure if codeigniter allows multiple database connections, you could try append a new set of database config rules.  SO $config['default']['..'] is default, add something like $config['connection2']['...']

Comment: Yeah I have already created a 2nd set of database values for my 2nd database in the config file. I just can't figure out how to either join the tables, or alternatively get the value from the the 'userid' field from the first query and then use it in a 2nd query in a 2nd function.

Comment: You wont be able to join now, You will need to do 2 queries... 1. grab your photos timestamp + user_id from connection1, 2.grab your users where id=user_id from connection2

Comment: That's what I thought, but how do I create a variable from the result of the 1st query and then pass it to the 2nd function (where it will be used in a 2nd query)?

Comment: In what order are the configurations? Thats important!

Comment: The database configurations? photos is first, users is second.